# What are the functions for which ${f f''\over f'^2} < 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

What are the functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ (with continuous first and second derivatives) that satisfy the following conditions:

- Monotonically increasing in $[0,1]$, with $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f(1)=1$;
- for all $x\in[0,1]$:

$$
{f(x) f''(x) \over f'(x)^2} < 2
$$

?

Some simple examples are:

- $f(x) = x^k$ for some $k> 0$. Then: $f(x)f''(x)=k(k-1)x^{2k-2}$ and $f'(x)^2 = k^2 x^{2k-2}$ so the quotient is $(k-1)/k < 1 < 2$.
- $f(x) = e^{k (x-1)}$ for some $k\geq 0$. Then: $f(x)f''(x) = k^2 f(x) = f'(x)$ so the quotient is $1 < 2$.

Is there a general form of functions that satisfy these conditions?

Comment: The second condition can be written as $(\frac {f(x)}{f'(x)})' \gt -1$

Comment: I very much doubt that an explicit description is possible, but one can certainly extract various first order differential inequalities, which lead to inequalities on $f$ by the comparison theorem. For example, we have that $L''<L'^2$, with $L=\log f$, and this gives that $f(x)<1/(1+f'(1)(x-1))$ for $x<1$, if I got the algebra right.

Comment: Your differential inequality says that ${1\over f}$ is convex.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Indeed! My condition seems to be equivalent to $f=1/g$ where $g$ is positive and decreasing, $g''>0$ and $g(1)=1$.

Comment: A nice observation: If $f$ is a real-valued polynomial, all of whose roots are real, then $ff''\le(f')^2$, with equality holding only at the double roots of $f$. This is sometimes called Turan's inequality, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232797/6085) for a bit more.

Comment: Nice question, by the way! Would you mind saying something about how this came up? I imagine something related to Newton's method.

Comment: Possibly helpful: An easier sufficient condition can be established by letting $g = ff'$ and rewriting the second property to $g' < 3g^2/f^2 \implies g' < 3/f(0)^2g^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x), f'(x)>0$ on [0,1]
$$
\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}<2\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
Then we can write
$$
\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}=2\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-g(x)
$$
where $g(x)>0$ on [0,1] but is otherwise arbitrary. Integrating from dummy variable t = x to 1:
$$
\ln{|f'(1)|}-\ln{|f'(x)|}=2\ln{|f(1)|}-2\ln{|f(x)|}-G(x)
$$
where $G(x)=\int_x^1{g(t)dt}$ is monotonically decreasing. Since $f(x), f'(x)>0$ on [0,1] the absolute values are irrelevant. Noting that $f(1)=1$, rearranging and taking exponents:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}=f'(1)e^{G(x)}
$$
Integrating from x to 1:
$$
\frac{-1}{f(1)}+\frac{1}{f(x)}=f'(1)\int_x^1{e^{G(t)}dt}
$$
or
$$
f(x)=\left[1+f'(1)\int_x^1{e^{G(t)}dt}\right]^{-1}
$$

As an example, choose $g(x)=1$ and $f'(1)=1$. Then
$$
G(x)=1-x
$$
(note that $G$ is monotonically decreasing)
$$
\int_x^1{e^{G(t)}dt}=e^{1-x}-1
$$
$$
f(x)=e^{x-1}
$$

Different choices of $g$ give different results for $f$. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think there is an error in the example - the integral of $1-x$ is not $e^{1-x}$...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Thanks Erel. I corrected the error you pointed out.

Comment: The integrations should be done in good condition, but its start to look like a solution

Answer (score 0):

**If this helps**: (too long for a comment)

$$\left(\frac1f\right)''=-\left(\frac{f'}{f^2}\right)'=-\frac{f''f^2-2ff'^2}{f^4}=\left(2-\frac{f''f}{f'^2}\right)\frac{f'^2}{f^3}.$$

So working with $g:=1/f$ might be easier.

$$gg''=\left(2-\frac{f''f}{f'^2}\right)g'^2$$ is positive.